# How to make the images in list each take you to a different page when you tap on them in flutter?

Tags: flutter

So i have a list with images and i added the images with ${index+1} and added ontap but every image i tap on sends me to the same page and i want every image to send me to it's own page that im gonna make for each one.

```dart
body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
          child: Column(children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Center(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 8,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                          return GestureDetector(
                       onTap:(){
                         Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                           builder: (context)=>PostScreen(),
                         ));

                       },

                       child: Center(
                         child: Container(
                           width: 160,
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                           margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             color: Colors.black,
                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                             image: DecorationImage(
                               //city1.jpg
                               image: AssetImage("images/city${index+1}.jpg"),
                               fit: BoxFit.cover,
                               opacity: 0.7,
                             ),
                           ),
                           child: Column(
                             children: [
                               Container(
                                 alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                 child: Icon(
                                   Icons.bookmark_border_outlined,
                                   color: Colors.white,
                                   size: 30,
                                 ),
                               ),
                               Spacer(),
                               Container(
                                   alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                                   child: Text(
                                       "city Name",
                                       style: TextStyle(
                                         color: Colors.white,
                                         fontSize: 15,
                                         fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                       )
                                   )
                               ),
                             ],
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),
                     );
                        } ),
                  ),),
                ),
              ],
```

I tried to put the images separately without the index and it just broke the app

Comment: If you are just trying to pass/show the image on next page, you can pass index(or image path) on `PostScreen(imageLink)`. if different page refers to different widget/route you can add condition on `onTap:(){`

Answer (score 0):

Right now you've the following code :

```
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                           builder: (context)=>PostScreen(),
  ));
```

So when any image is clicked, it will redirect to PostScreen.

Now, if you want to make it redirect to screens as per image selection, you can use the index here.

I will show it using pushNamed() method.

You should make a list of screen names, each one per image and use the same index as image to navigate to that screen inside your GestureDetector.

For example, create a list as follows inside your widget :

List screens = ['image_1_screen', 'image_2_screen', 'image_3_screen'];

Now, use it like :

```
return GestureDetector(
        onTap:(){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, screens[index]);
        }
);
```

So, it will redirect to relevant screen as per the image selected.

In short, make a list of the screens and use the same index as an image to navigate to that particular screen.

Comment: im sorry if the question sounds dumb(im not too experienced with flutter) but how should i make a list inside gesturedetector?

Comment: That list should be defined before your build() method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a list of your image files. before your build

```
final List imagesPath = ["images/1.png","images/2.png", "images/3.png"];
```

Now, make these changes in listView.builder:

```
itemCount: 8 to itemCount: imagesPath.length
AssetImage("images/city${index+1}.jpg") to AssetImage(imagesPath[index])
```

Then In your PostScreen class you need to create a final String variable name assetPath and make it as required in its contructor. and in your PostScreen build return Image.asset(path). The code should look like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PostScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final String assetPath;

  const PostScreen({Key? key, required this.assetPath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Image.asset(assetPath),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now, inside gesture detector you need to pass "assetPath":

```
onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              const PostScreen(assetPath: imagesPath[index]),
                        ));
           },
```

So, lets just say. you click on the 3rd image its index will be 2. then it will pass the path of 2nd image from the list to your PostScreen().

Comment: my postscreen screen it's split in 2 screens, one for the background image and the other for the info on the screen, do i have to put the string in both of them?

Comment: No, why would you do that? assetPath is path of your photo that you clicked from your previous page and passed it to post screen.  if you want to show the info about the photo, then create another list and more string variable like assetPath and make it required in constructor and pass it from your previous page.